# Mysql - PDO Error - Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with PDO, and I see absolutely no where he come. I can not question my MySQL database. Just to test I used the following code (having quite sour previously configured the parameters for the connection:

```
$dbh= new PDO('mysql:host=serverName;dbname=Mydatabase','user','password');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

var_dump($dbh);    // gives : object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

$res=$dbh->query('SELECT * FROM table');
```

The connection is made correctly with MySQL but after query I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in /home/outout/public_html/file.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/outout/public_html/file.php(16): PDO->query('select * from t...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/outout/public_html/file.php on line 16.

The code works on a local machine, but as soon as I put it online (cPanel) it shows me this error. Do I have to configure PDO in .htaccess?

I absolutely do not understand where the problem come. Someone would have an idea?

Comment: The error is very clear : `No database selected` !! so verify the name of your db.

Comment: i verify the name of my db, and i see it's correct thanks

Comment: Without knowing what your MySQL host and database name are on your CPanel host and whether or not they match the parameters in your DSN (first argument to the `PDO` constructor), this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @user3714770 Try also to verify your host, I think for shared hosting, it's usually `localhost`.

Comment: @akmozo thank you so much it works with localhost :) but localhost it is not for the local machine !!

Comment: @user3714770 For sever security reasons, we use `localhost` to avoid external connections. Localhost here represent your server.

Comment: ah okay, thank you you're the person of my evening :) rabi ybarak fik

Answer (score 17):

You made some mistake or a typo. Make sure that database *exists on the server you are connecting to* and correctly set in the DSN like this

```
dbname=Mydatabase;
```

without spaces or other symbols. Character case is also important.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=serverName;dbname=Mydatabase;charset=utf8mb4','user','pass');
```

should work

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem while not mentioning the 'host' string with 'mysql' (mysql:host). I solved the problem by following code.

```
$dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,"root","");
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
$res=$dbh->query('SELECT * FROM table');
```

just do:

```
  $res=$dbh->query('SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename');
```

You will be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I faced same problem. Resolution of problem was removed the space between hostname and dbname variable as follows:
From:
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $servername;dbname = $dbname", $username, $password);

To:
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

Answer (score 0):

What tripped me up was that I copied the database name from the tree in MySQL workbench and pasted it into the settings.php file.
Turns out that the apostrophes at the beginning and end of the string are fake apostrophes! I deleted them and put in real apostrophes and everything fired right up. Took me several hours to figure this out.
Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

***use keyword same dbname dont change them***

```
public function conect(){
        $this->conn = null;
        
        try {

       $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
     //    $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }
        return $this->conn;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$dbh= new PDO('mysql:host=serverName;dbname=Mydatabase','user','password');
```

This here is wrong. You can't have host=serverName, instead you need to have something like host=$serverName, and then the $serverName = "servername.domanin"; the same with dbname=Mydatabase, you need to make those variables, $Mydatabase="mydatabase" it should look like this:

```
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo "Connection ok!";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Err: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;
```

this will work.
More details on: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

I had the same error, and it was because instead of using dbname=$dbname in string i used $dbname=$dbname, just a typo. You need to write the string correctly !

Comment: I bet you $5 that he was just using placeholders instead of giving us the actual names

Answer (score -1):

To whomever is facing the same problem, in the dsn if you type port before dbname, it gives the same error

so replace

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;port:$this->port;dbname=$this->db;charset=UTF8;";
```

with

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db;port:$this->port;charset=UTF8;";
```

notice the order of **port** and **dbname**

Comment: it was a colon, not the order of variables

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
$database -> query(' SELECT * FROM "database_name"."table_name" ');
```

instead of

```
$database -> query(' SELECT * FROM "table_name" ');
```