# Query failed: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

dbConn.php

```php
<?php
function getConnection()
{
    try {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;*****=username", "*****", "*****");
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $connection;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception("Connection error " . $e->getMessage(), 0, $e);
    }
}

?>
```

Admin page:

```php
<?php
try {
    require_once("dbconn.php");
    $dbConn = getConnection();

    $sqlQuery = "SELECT eventID, eventTitle, eventDescription, NE_events.venueID, venueName, location, NE_events.catID, catDesc, eventStartDate, eventEndDate, eventPrice 
            FROM NE_events
            INNER JOIN NE_category
            ON NE_category.catID = NE_events.catID
            INNER JOIN NE_venue
            ON NE_venue.venueID = NE_events.venueID
            ORDER BY eventTitle";
    $queryResult = $dbConn->query($sqlQuery);

    while ($rowObj = $queryResult->fetchObject()) {
        echo "<div class='event'>\n
        <span class='eventTitle'>{$rowObj->eventTitle}</span>\n
        <span class='categoryName'>{$rowObj->catDesc}</span>\n
        <span class='venue'>{$rowObj->venueName}</span>\n
        <span class='startDate'>($rowObj->eventStartDate)</span>\n
        <span class='endDate'>($rowObj->eventEndDate)</span>\n
        <span class='price'>($rowObj->eventPrice)</span>
    </div>\n";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<p>Query failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>\n";
}
?>
```

[image: My dbConn.php file]
[image: My admin page]

I'm trying to retrieve data from MySQL database, but for some reason I get an error saying:

> Query failed: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected.

Comment: I removed the pass and username on the dbConn for security reasons.

Comment: The connection should be something like `'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';`

Comment: sorry about the @gander , i have added the code as a text

Comment: What is `*****=username`? Where is your database name?

Comment: @NigelRen it is structured like that but i have blurred it , still same error tho

Comment: @Dharman i blured it for security reasons

Comment: Blurred what? I don't want to know your username of password, but what was that part in the DSN?

Comment: I can't provide you with the code as I don't know php that well. It seems to me however, that you have not provided your application with the name of the database it should be using. You need to provide php with a database name it should select.

Comment: Hey, can you take a look to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754835/mysql-pdo-error-invalid-catalog-name-1046-no-database-selected

There is no answer working for your problem ?

Comment: the ****=username, this is the dbname and it= to my username, they are the same thing

Comment: i edited the connection.php above so it can be more understandable

Comment: Are you sure this database exists?

Comment: Try adding database name to the table you wanna query like 
`FROM Mydatabase.MytableName`
As this is suggest here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732629/6503197

Comment: @Dharman yeah im sure

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE i have tried that but stil the same error

Comment: Can you access the database via CLI? or via any other MySQL management tool?

Answer (score 1):

As Nigel Ren mentioned you should specify the database name in a DSN string (1st param of PDO constructor).

```php
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourDbName", "login", "password");
```

The error you get clearly states that you don't have DB selected.

Answer (score -1):

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
write this line correctly

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made